# Testing c++ console output via TDD

Tags: c++, unit-testing, boost, console, tdd

I am writing c++ program using Test Driven Development Approach.
I have a function which uses console output.
I would like to write a test which is able to test whether the console output is the same like the expected output.
I saw this can be solved and should be checked. But I saw solutions in this forum not in c++ but in other languages. I suppose it can be done in C++ too.

Any hint would be a great help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't write directly to the console; write to a stream that's provided to the function.

The test can provide a `stringstream`, and extract the output from that. A real program can provide `cout` (or something else) to get real output.

In general: write code that interacts with abstract interfaces, which can be mocked for tests, rather than concrete implementations, which can't.

Comment: Depending on what the OP means by "uses console output", this may be what is already done, or it may be totally unrealistic (for e.g. use of ncurses). We need some clarification. It's a bad question as originally posed.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: OIndeed, if it uses something other than a stream, then you'd need to provide a different abstraction. But the principle's the same: interact with abstract interfaces, which can be mocked by tests, not with concrete implementations, which can't.

Comment: I meant this exactly. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I can advice you on the general approach to make your code testable: Thing you can do is to pass the output stream as a parameter to your unit, so that in test setup you can pass one you can do your checks on, and in production setup the standard output...